# Cocos2d Chipmunk: Custom shapes?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, shapes, chipmunk

In my application i try to make custom shapes by using `addPoly`, but it doesen't seem to work at all! :(

I think i don't understand how to use it at all... :(

Here's my attempt of creating a simple square:

```
cpShape *square = [smgr addPolyAt:cpv(240,160) mass:100 rotation:0 numPoints:4 points:cpv(0, -10), cpv(10, 0), cpv(0, 10), cpv(-10, 0)];
```

I just don't get how to use it; can you help me plz???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these points: `cpv(0, 0), cpv(10, 0), cpv(10, -10), cpv(0, -10)`
Remember you can't create the polygon counterclockwise (always clockwise) and you can't just add the points in any order! By the way if you don't have a sprite associated to the shape use
`[self addChild:[smgr createDebugLayer]];` to show the shape in the simulator. 
Greetings Alex...feel free to ask any follow up questions

Comment: hello, the app doesn't crash anymore, but the created poly has some strange physics of it's own... As it falls to the ground it starts jumping around, finally as it calms down, it begins to slowly roll to the left. Any idea whats happening? :D

Comment: Und gleich noch eine Frage: Wie funktioniert das alles eigendlich? Und wie kann ich beim Rechteck nur eine ecke vershieben?